# Animate route that is going out / being replaced

Tags: dart, flutter

I made simple fade page transition via following implementation:

```
return new PageRouteBuilder(
  opaque: true,
  pageBuilder: (BuildContext context, Animation<double> animation,
      Animation<double> secondaryAnimation) {
    return new FadeTransition(opacity: animation, child: route);
});
```

It does the trick when new page comes in, it fades in new page, but old one is still visible while new one is not 100% faded in.

Ideally I'd like this to work in a way where previous page fades out first, then new one fades in. I know that I can use secondaryAnimation for this somehow, but can't currently figure it out. I tried nesting another `FadeTransition` as a child and using it, but in this case my route just fades in quickly and goes away (as secondary is now 0)

**Edit**: this is not using `MaterialApp`, its based on `WidgetsApp`

**Edit2**: Found out that I can also use `isInitialRoute` from settings of the router, can I apply this here somehow?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From Flutter source code annotations:

```
/// Signature for the [PageRouteBuilder] function that builds the route's
/// transitions.
///
/// See [ModalRoute.buildTransitions] for complete definition of the parameters.
typedef Widget RouteTransitionsBuilder(BuildContext context, Animation<double> animation, Animation<double> secondaryAnimation, Widget child);
```

and further:

````
  /// We've used [PageRouteBuilder] to demonstrate the [buildTransitions] method
  /// here. The body of an override of the [buildTransitions] method would be
  /// defined in the same way.
  ///
  /// When the [Navigator] pushes a route on the top of its stack, the
  /// [secondaryAnimation] can be used to define how the route that was on
  /// the top of the stack leaves the screen. Similarly when the topmost route
  /// is popped, the secondaryAnimation can be used to define how the route
  /// below it reappears on the screen. When the Navigator pushes a new route
  /// on the top of its stack, the old topmost route's secondaryAnimation
  /// runs from 0.0 to 1.0.  When the Navigator pops the topmost route, the
  /// secondaryAnimation for the route below it runs from 1.0 to 0.0.
  ///
  /// The example below adds a transition that's driven by the
  /// [secondaryAnimation]. When this route disappears because a new route has
  /// been pushed on top of it, it translates in the opposite direction of
  /// the new route. Likewise when the route is exposed because the topmost
  /// route has been popped off.
  ///
  /// ```dart
  ///   transitionsBuilder: (
  ///       BuildContext context,
  ///       Animation<double> animation,
  ///       Animation<double> secondaryAnimation,
  ///       Widget child,
  ///   ) {
  ///     return new SlideTransition(
  ///       position: new AlignmentTween(
  ///         begin: const Offset(0.0, 1.0),
  ///         end: Offset.zero,
  ///       ).animate(animation),
  ///       child: new SlideTransition(
  ///         position: new TweenOffset(
  ///           begin: Offset.zero,
  ///           end: const Offset(0.0, 1.0),
  ///         ).animate(secondaryAnimation),
  ///         child: child,
  ///       ),
  ///     );
  ///   }
  /// ```
  ///
  /// In practice the `secondaryAnimation` is used pretty rarely.
  ///
  /// The arguments to this method are as follows:
  ///
  ///  * `context`: The context in which the route is being built.
  ///  * [animation]: When the [Navigator] pushes a route on the top of its stack,
  ///    the new route's primary [animation] runs from 0.0 to 1.0. When the [Navigator]
  ///    pops the topmost route this animation runs from 1.0 to 0.0.
  ///  * [secondaryAnimation]: When the Navigator pushes a new route
  ///    on the top of its stack, the old topmost route's [secondaryAnimation]
  ///    runs from 0.0 to 1.0.  When the [Navigator] pops the topmost route, the
  ///    [secondaryAnimation] for the route below it runs from 1.0 to 0.0.
  ///  * `child`, the page contents.
  ///
  /// See also:
  ///
  ///  * [buildPage], which is used to describe the actual contents of the page,
  ///    and whose result is passed to the `child` argument of this method.
````

My personal suggestion is when doc is vague or missing to search in the code ;)

Best

Comment: I tried their example of using secondaryAnimation, but it is broken. Updated the TweenOffset and AlignmentTween to Tween<Offset> to get rid of compile errors, but still doesnt work. I dont understand how it would know what widget to animate as only the new widget that is comming in is declared and used as the child parameter. I probably need to try this out in a fresh new project, but did you get it working? I would like to get the effect that the current route is translated backwards in Z position at the same time as the new route is coming in.

Comment: This does not animate underlying old screen

Comment: this does not exemplify how to make it work with fade transitions

Answer (score -1):

[Dartpad here.](https://dartpad.dev/?id=2c787703e40d28ae34f1d5a8da0c7f95)

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.amber,
      ),
      home: const MyHomePage(replace: true),
    );
  }
}

class SecondRoute extends StatelessWidget {
  const SecondRoute({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Colors.redAccent.shade400,
      body: Center(
        child: TextButton.icon(
          onPressed: () {
            Navigator.of(context).pop();
          },
          icon: const Icon(Icons.arrow_back_rounded),
          label: const Text('Return to 1st route'),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyHomePage({Key? key, required this.replace}) : super(key: key);
  final bool replace;

  @override
  State<MyHomePage> createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  Route _createRoute(Widget newRoute) {
    return PageRouteBuilder(
      pageBuilder: (BuildContext context, Animation<double> animation, Animation<double> secondaryAnimation) {
        return Align(
          alignment: Alignment.topCenter,
          child: SizeTransition(
            sizeFactor: Tween<double>(begin: 1.0, end: 0.0)
                .animate(CurvedAnimation(parent: secondaryAnimation, curve: Curves.linearToEaseOut)),
            axisAlignment: -1.0,
            child: newRoute,
          ),
        );
      },
      transitionDuration: const Duration(milliseconds: 800),
      reverseTransitionDuration: const Duration(milliseconds: 800),
      transitionsBuilder:
          (BuildContext context, Animation<double> animation, Animation<double> secondaryAnimation, Widget child) {
        return SlideTransition(
          position: Tween<Offset>(begin: const Offset(0.0, 1.0), end: Offset.zero)
              .animate(CurvedAnimation(parent: animation, curve: Curves.easeInOutQuart)),
          child: child,
        );
      },
    );
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    WidgetsBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback((Duration timeStamp) {
      //THE REASON FOR DOING THIS: MAIN ROUTE HAS TO BE PUSHED WITH THE CUSTOM ROUTE AS WELL, OTHERWISE IT DOESN'T WORK, SO THIS IS THE BEST SOLUTION I CAME UP WITH.
      if (widget.replace) {
        Navigator.of(context).pushReplacement(_createRoute(const MyHomePage(replace: false)));
      }
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Colors.blueAccent.shade400,
      body: Center(
        child: TextButton.icon(
          onPressed: () {
            Navigator.of(context).push(_createRoute(const SecondRoute()));
          },
          icon: const Icon(Icons.arrow_forward_rounded),
          label: const Text('Go to 2nd route'),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```