# How to animate old page during transition in flutter?

Tags: flutter, customization, transition

I made a custom transition for my iOS project, and now I want to move the project to Flutter. The transition is fading out the old page, and fading in the new one.

But I cannot achieve this by overriding the PageRoute.

I did some research on this:

There's a similar question
[Animate route that is going out / being replaced](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48138595/animate-route-that-is-going-out-being-replaced)

From the accepted answer, I know there's a parameter 'secondaryAnimation' which may be useful to achieve it, but after trying to use the code from it, I still cannot animate the old page, all transitions have happened to the new page (the 'child' widget).

Can I get an 'old page' instance from the buildTransition method for animating? Or is there a better way to animate the old page?

Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

I think that `secondaryAnimation` is used when transitioning to another page. So for your initial route, you'd have to specify the animation of it going away using `secondaryAnimation` and on your second page you use `animation` to animate how it appears.

It's a bit awkward that you have to use `secondaryAnimation` when creating the first route, because it means that it will be used for any transition away from that route. So, with `PageRouteBuilder`, you can't, for example, let the old page slide to the left when transitioning to page B but slide up when transitioning to page C.

Answer (score 0):

I wrote two classes to achieve animating the old page.

- `PageSwitcherBuilder` is a widget builder to animate old page.
- `PageSwitcherRoute` is a route class to navigate new page.

Examples on [DartPad](https://dartpad.dev/1c6f7f25fda6a2ac90f14f289a131bee)

Here is my script.

```
class PageSwitcherBuilder extends StatefulWidget {
  const PageSwitcherBuilder(
      {Key? key,
      required this.builder,
      this.duration = const Duration(milliseconds: 500),
      this.reverseDuration = const Duration(milliseconds: 500)})
      : super(key: key);
  final Duration duration;
  final Duration reverseDuration;
  final Widget Function(AnimationController controller) builder;

  @override
  State<PageSwitcherBuilder> createState() => _PageSwitcherBuilderState();
}

class _PageSwitcherBuilderState extends State<PageSwitcherBuilder>
    with TickerProviderStateMixin {
  late final AnimationController _controller = AnimationController(
    vsync: this,
    duration: widget.duration,
    reverseDuration: widget.reverseDuration,
  );

  @override
  void dispose() {
    _controller.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return widget.builder(_controller);
  }
}

class PageSwitcherRoute extends PageRouteBuilder {
  PageSwitcherRoute({
    required this.controller,
    required Widget page,
  }) : super(pageBuilder: (BuildContext context, Animation<double> animation,
            Animation<double> secondaryAnimation) {
          return page;
        }) {
    willDisposeAnimationController = false;
  }

  @override
  final AnimationController controller;

  @override
  AnimationController createAnimationController() {
    return controller;
  }
}
```

You may also check this [ZoomPageTransitionsBuilder](https://docs.flutter.dev/release/breaking-changes/page-transition-replaced-by-ZoomPageTransitionBuilder) class to change default transitions.

Answer (score 0):

Workaround that I've come up with is to observe pushes and pops of routes and animte during these.

1. Create a Route Wrapper using [RouteObserver](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/RouteObserver-class.html)
2. Run animation on `didPushNext`
3. Reverse animation on `didPopNext`
4. Wrap all screens that you want to animate on exit and on reenter.

```
 import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

 class ScreenSlideTransition extends StatefulWidget {
  const ScreenSlideTransition({super.key, required this.child});
  final Widget child;

  @override
  State<ScreenSlideTransition> createState() => _ScreenSlideTransitionState();
}

class _ScreenSlideTransitionState extends State<ScreenSlideTransition>
    with RouteAware, TickerProviderStateMixin {

  late final AnimationController _controller;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final screenWidth = -MediaQuery.of(context).size.width;
    return AnimatedBuilder( // Whatever animation you need goes here
        animation: _controller,
        builder: (BuildContext context, Widget? child) => Transform.translate(
            offset: Offset(screenWidth * _controller.value, 0),
            child: widget.child));
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _controller = AnimationController(
        vsync: this, duration: const Duration(milliseconds: 1000));
  }

  @override
  void didChangeDependencies() {
    super.didChangeDependencies();
    routeObserver.subscribe(this, ModalRoute.of(context)!);
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    _controller.dispose();
    routeObserver.unsubscribe(this);
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  void didPopNext() {
    _controller.reverse();
    super.didPopNext();
  }

  @override
  void didPushNext() {
    _controller.forward();
    super.didPushNext();
  }
}
```

In order to make the above code work make sure to initialise RouteObserver ([see docs](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/RouteObserver-class.html))

```
final RouteObserver<ModalRoute<void>> routeObserver = RouteObserver<ModalRoute<void>>();

void main() {
  runApp(MaterialApp(
    home: Container(),
    navigatorObservers: <RouteObserver<ModalRoute<void>>>[ routeObserver ],
  ));
}
```

Remember to set the same Duration for `AnimationController` in `ScreenSlideTransition` and duration for `transitionsBuilder` if you want to synchronise in/out animation.