# Flutter PageRouteBuilder transitionsBuilder customize secondary animation?

Tags: android, ios, flutter, dart

In PageRouteBuilder's transitionBuilder method I'm using the code bellow but the secondary animation is ALWAYS the reverse of the animation. How can we have a slide in transition on a page and fade out on exit?

```
Widget leftToRightSlideTransition(context, animation, secondaryAnimation, child) {
  final Tween<double> doubleTween = Tween<double>(begin: 1.0, end: 0.0);
  final Animation<double> animDouble = doubleTween.animate(secondaryAnimation);
  final fadeTransition = FadeTransition(opacity: animDouble, child: child);

  var begin = Offset(-1.0, 0.0);
  var end = Offset.zero;
  var tween = Tween(begin: begin, end: end).chain(
    CurveTween(curve: Curves.easeIn),
  );
  return SlideTransition(
    position: tween.animate(animation),
    child: fadeTransition,
  );
}
```

Answer (score 3):

If you want custom animations for enter and exit pages you need put `SlideTransition` to `Stack` widget for enter page and exit page. Here is exemple how should look iOS `SlideTransition` (Cupertino).

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class CupertinoRoute extends PageRouteBuilder {
  final Widget enterPage;
  final Widget exitPage;
  CupertinoRoute({this.exitPage, this.enterPage})
      : super(
          pageBuilder: (
            BuildContext context,
            Animation<double> animation,
            Animation<double> secondaryAnimation,
          ) {
            return enterPage;
          },
          transitionsBuilder: (
            BuildContext context,
            Animation<double> animation,
            Animation<double> secondaryAnimation,
            Widget child,
          ) {
            return Stack(
              children: <Widget>[
                SlideTransition(
                  position: Tween<Offset>(
                    begin: const Offset(0.0, 0.0),
                    end: const Offset(-0.33, 0.0),
                  ).animate(
                      CurvedAnimation(
                      parent: animation,
                      curve: Curves.linearToEaseOut,
                      reverseCurve: Curves.easeInToLinear,
                    ),
                      ),
                  child: exitPage,
                ),
                SlideTransition(
                  position: Tween<Offset>(
                    begin: const Offset(1.0, 0.0),
                    end: Offset.zero,
                  ).animate(
                      CurvedAnimation(
                      parent: animation,
                      curve: Curves.linearToEaseOut,
                      reverseCurve: Curves.easeInToLinear,
                    ),
                      ),
                  child: enterPage,
                )
              ],
            );
          },
        );
}
```

and here you can customize animations how you want to both `SlideTransition`.

```dart
// And use it like this
Navigator.push(
        context,
        CupertinoRoute(
            exitPage: HomeScreen(),
            enterPage: SecondScreen()));
```

Comment: Thanks, Will try this solution. It'll require to know previously which routes are currently loaded to pass to the enter page and exit page, so it's another thing to maintain.

Comment: I have the same problem [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67164148/how-to-animate-routes-transtion-relative-to-the-previous-one-in-flutter/67280651#67280651) and this is a hack, it looks bad when the previous route has a state change like scroll...an imporoved answer is apreciated

Comment: I have added generic parameter to class decloration