# Navigator.of(context).pop without animation

Tags: flutter, navigation

I am using `CupertinoTabScaffold` in my flutter app. I can open page with particular item on the first tab and remove it from the second one. Page with removed item can't be opened, so I call `Navigator.of(context).pop` from this page in `Redux Store callback`. This works but the problem is I see animation when I open first tab (it starts at the moment when I click on this tab). How can I make `Navigator.of(context).pop` without animation?

Could someone help me? Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

If you want to disable transition animation when navigating between page when pushing just wrap it in PageRouteBuilder

```
Navigator.of(context).push(PageRouteBuilder(
              pageBuilder: (context, _, __) {
                return Page();
              },
            ));
```

That will disable both enter and exit transition.

You can read more about the subject here 
https://medium.com/flutter-community/everything-you-need-to-know-about-flutter-page-route-transition-9ef5c1b32823

Comment: I need pages to change with animation when this tab is active and without animation when It's not

Comment: Then you need implement enter transition by yourself and don't do transition animation on exit. You can read more how to do that here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52762069/flutter-transition-exit